# I am trying to read the formatted texts from files by using fscanf(), but it gives me a disgusting output

Tags: c, string, pointers, format, scanf

**Output is a bunch of zeros besided the printing of the name,code, salary and age, so where is the mistake, it keeps printing in an unformatted way**

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(void)
{
    //reading formatted text from a file.

    int code;
    char name[35];
    int age;
    float salary;

    FILE *pointer_;

    if ( (pointer_= fopen("Formated.txt","r"))==NULL)
        {
            printf("File is corrupted.");
        }

    while((fscanf(pointer_,"%d",&code))!=EOF)
        {
            fgets(name,35,pointer_);
            fscanf(pointer_,"%d", &age);
            fscanf(pointer_,"%f", &salary);
            printf("%-5d %-35s %-2d %-7.2f",code,name,age,salary);
        }

    fclose(pointer_);
}
```

Comment: Let me be the first to reply, "What does the input look like?" Edit the question and add a few sample lines of the input. (There are obvious problems here, but without seeing the input, any response can only be guesswork...)

Comment: You should check the return values from fscanf(). It tells you how many items it converted, and it could be zero if it converted none. Mixing fscanf() and fgets() like this is a bit dubious. You haven't shared what the format of your Formatted.txt file is, but there are probably better ways to parse it.

Comment: I think you need to use something other than `fscanf` and `fgets` here. Maybe a small parser is in order. Also, why `35`? *Magic numbers* like this need to be properly defined in a way that's self-explanatory. Even `int name_len = 35` is a start.

Comment: 0x0040Coder, Post sample input and its _disgusting output_.

Answer (score 1):

**Leftover `'\n'`**

`fscanf(pointer_,"%d"...` does not consume any `'\n'` that may follow the numeric text, thus the following `fgets()` reads that line remnant.

```
while((fscanf(pointer_,"%d",&code))!=EOF)
        {
            fgets(name,35,pointer_);  // May only reads a `\n`.
```

**Lack of result checking**

The return values of `fgets(name,35,pointer_); fscanf(pointer_,"%d", &age); fscanf(pointer_,"%f", &salary);` are not checked.  Unless they are as expected, assuming a good read is folly.

**Look for unexpected data after the desired input on each line.**

**Recommend to read only with `fgets()`**

After successfully reading the lines of data, parse them and check for parsing success.

**If still wanting to use `fscanf()`**

Check the return values.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use constants `NAME_LEN` instead of hard-coding magic values, especially when you repeat that value 3 times.
2. You need to check the return value of all your I/O operations otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized values.  Any and all of these could encounter `EOF` of the stream.  I used a couple of macros here to make the normal case more readable while still affecting the control in the error case.
3. `fgets()` reads a line so the following `fscanf()` will fail if your input file `Formated.txt` [sic] doesn't contain a `\n' after the name field:

```
1 name
2 3.0
2 name2
3 4.0
```

4. As you are reading the file it's not strictly required but it's a good idea `fclose()` the file before exit.
5. It's a good practice to reduce variable scope as much as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHECK_N(v, n, msg) {\
    int tmp = (v);\
    if(tmp == EOF) {\
        rv = EXIT_SUCCESS;\
        break;\
    }\
    if(tmp != n) {\
        printf("%s\n", msg);\
        break;\
    }\
}
#define CHECK_STR(s, msg) {\
    char *tmp = (s);\
    if(!tmp) {\
        if(feof(pointer_)) {\
            rv = EXIT_SUCCESS;\
            break;\
        }\
        printf("%s", msg);\
        break;\
    }\
}
#define NAME_LEN 35
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

int main() {
    int rv = EXIT_FAILURE;
    FILE *pointer_ = fopen("Formated.txt","r");
    if(!pointer_) {
        printf("fopen failed");
        return rv;
    }
    for(;;) {
        int code;
        CHECK_N(fscanf(pointer_,"%d", &code), 1, "code");

        char name[NAME_LEN];
        CHECK_STR(fgets(name, sizeof(name), pointer_), "name");
        name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';

        int age;
        float salary;
        CHECK_N(fscanf(pointer_,"%d %f", &age, &salary), 2, "age and salary");

        printf("%-5d %-" str(NAME_LEN) "s %-2d %-7.2f\n", code, name, age, salary);
    }
    fclose(pointer_);
    return rv;
}
```

and example output with the above mentioned input.  Note that I replaced the `\n` in `name` with `\0' to format it like this:

```
1      name                               2  3.00   
2      name2                              3  4.00
```

Comment: 'E' for effort... but would still break if "name" turned out to be `Supercalifragilisticexpialidoutious` (36 characters and spelling dubious...)  `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 If with "break" you mean "expected behavior" for invalid input.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: Salient is that the OP hasn't supplied any sample input, so anything is possible... It could be that the "formatted" text is actually a CSV (with those worries, too.) OP seems to have wandered off somewhere so any/every interpretation of "formatted" becomes possible. Recent question about "checking XML" suggests "formatted" could even mean XML, and the i/o functions should just _know_ what the programmer intended...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The macros are kinda ugly (and I don't mean the semi-duplication)... any ideas for a cleaner approach that doesn't result in  doubling code size of main with conditionals?

Comment: Hard to say... "disgusting output" may just be that the OP doesn't output LF at the end of their string (as your code does...) `:-)` Oh, the fun... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 My mommy taught me that all data is beautiful (jk).  My guess is binary data from an uninitialized variable.